# Eclipse with Groovy-eclipse not showing New > Groovy Class option

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I'm using Eclipse 4.9. I used the Install Software option to add groovy-eclipse from the URL `http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.9`.

No errors on this part:
[image: install software showing no errors]

I created a new Groovy Project named *FirstG* initial module named *firstg*:
[image: project and initial module .java]

Now when I go to *File > New > Other*, I do not see an option to add a Groovy Class:
[image: no groovy class option]

According to [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Groovy/article.html#install_springgroovytools), I should see this option.

Does anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you skip the eclipse restart after installing the plugin?

Comment: No, I restarted. I can see the option to create a Groovy Project, Groovy Test, and Groovy Type, but not a Groovy Class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the Groovy Class Wizard has been extended and renamed to "Groovy Type".

Source:
https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/commit/f30ccdb6fb3a3e4cbaa75477beceef78fc1bb3f7

Comment: That seems to be it.   Clicking that creates the .groovy file I was looking for.  Thanks,